# maven assembly plugin ignoring classifier in exclude

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin, multi-module

I am using the maven assembly plugin version 2.4 on maven 3.0.4 with java 7

Here is an extract from my assembly descriptor:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">

     <!--...some stuff skipped here...->

      <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
          <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
          <includes>
            <include>com.mycompany.myproject.ugui:ugui-application</include>
          </includes>
          <excludes>
            <exclude>com.mycompany.myproject.ugui:ugui-application:war:*:sources</exclude>
          </excludes>
          <binaries>
            <outputDirectory>war-file</outputDirectory>
            <unpack>false</unpack>
          </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
      </moduleSets>
```

The xsd for the maven assembly claims that the format I am using for the exclude is correct...

```
  <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="excludes">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation source="version">1.0.0+</xs:documentation>
      <xs:documentation source="description">

        When &amp;lt;exclude&amp;gt; subelements are present, they define a set of
        dependency artifact coordinates to exclude. If none is present, then
        &amp;lt;excludes&amp;gt; represents no exclusions.

        Artifact coordinatess may be given in simple groupId:artifactId form,
        or they may be fully qualified in the form groupId:artifactId:type:version[:classifier].
        Additionally, wildcards can be used, as in *:maven-*

      </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="exclude" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

However when I run the assembly it cannot make sense of the exclude...

```
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4:single (make-deployment-tar-zip-file) @ ugui-deploy ---
[INFO] Reading assembly descriptor: /home/fitzpatr/code/trunk/unicorn-ui/ugui-deploy/src/main/assembly/assembly.xml
[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact exclusion filter:
o  'com.mycompany.myproject.ugui:ugui-application:war:*:sources'

[WARNING] The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact exclusion filter:
o  'com.mycompany.myproject.ugui:ugui-application:war:*:sources'
```

... and the sources which I am trying to exclude are included in the assembly tar...

```
$ tar -tvf ugui-deploy/target/ugui-deploy-1.8-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz 
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 83885791 2014-02-26 15:39 ugui-deploy-1.8-SNAPSHOT/war-file/ugui-application-1.8-SNAPSHOT.war
-rw-rw-r-- user/usser    65220 2014-01-17 11:30 ugui-deploy-1.8-SNAPSHOT/war-file/ugui-application-1.8-SNAPSHOT-sources.war
-rw-rw-r-- user/user        0 2014-02-25 18:13 ugui-deploy-1.8-SNAPSHOT/README.txt
```

...so I am doing this wrong or is the maven assembly plugin broken???

Comment: Please check you assembly descriptor, cause based on the docs on the web site the includes/excludes look like this: [`groupId:artifactId:type[:classifier]:version`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_moduleSet)

Comment: Have you checked this?

Comment: Yes I have checked it, the classifier just does not work.

Comment: Would the down-voter please provide some constructive feedback, thanks.

Comment: Would the down voter please justify themselves. What is wrong with the question???

Answer (score 2):

The problem is solved by using a not very intuitive hack, exclude everything inside the binary element...

```
  <moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
      <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
      <includes>
        <include>com.mycompany.myproject.ugui:ugui-application</include>
      </includes>
      <binaries>
        <outputDirectory>war-file</outputDirectory>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </binaries>
    </moduleSet>
  </moduleSets>
```

...which yields the desired result...

```
$ tar -tvf ugui-deploy/target/ugui-deploy-1.8-SNAPSHOT-bin.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 0 2014-02-25 18:13 ugui-deploy-1.8-SNAPSHOT/README.txt
-rw-rw-r-- user/user 83885789 2014-02-26 16:49 ugui-deploy-1.8-SNAPSHOT/war-file/ugui-application-1.8-SNAPSHOT.war
```